# Difference between a Bardiche and a Voulge?

Tags: middle-ages, weapons

After having some interaction with some media involving medieval warfare, I noticed that a Voulge and a Bardiche are very similar in design and (possibly) purpose. I haven't done a full historical research on them, but by looking at some images, they appear to be very similar. What is the difference between them? Time periods, kingdoms to have used them?

Comment: The corresponding Wikipedia pages for the [Voulge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voulge) and [Bardiche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bardiche) seems to cover their history and differences.